# CSS @media print rule does not work anymore?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Previously, the following code works fine for both Firefox and Google Chrome when I print to "hide" the element,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .noprint { 
        display: none; 
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="noprint">abc</span>
</body></html>
```

But now, it does not work for both browsers. However, if I change to this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.noprint { 
    display: none; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="noprint">abc</span>
</body></html>
```

It will work on Firefox, but not on Google Chrome.
What is the solution which works as browser independent?
(Or is there something wrong with my code?)

Comment: `<style>` doesn't have a `rel="stylesheet"` attribute.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, sorry, that was my mistake. But even I remove the rel="stylesheet", \@media print still cannot work.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using @media print, you need to add !important in your styles, or the page will use the elements inline styles.

E.g.

```
@media print {
   .myelement1, .myelement2 { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: works for me, not sure why im not having to change it. probable a chrome error by the sounds of it

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is the problem with the Google Chrome, but today I tested again with Google Chrome version `31.0.1650`, the solution with `< style media="print" >` works well.

And `"@media print"` rule is still not working.

Comment: Seeing something similar in 35.x.x.x however, something is now broken with either option. looking for some other workaround.

Answer (score 1):

`"@media print"` & `< style media="print" >` both working fine on Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) Mac-OS & Firefox 34.0.5 Mac-OS

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have a style rule in your non-print sheet cascading over your print sheet rule. You are using a form of "internal" or embedded styling (not inline or external) that has higher selectivity in the cascade order over external styles but not inline. A true inline style in your HTML or in a screen style sheet with higher selectivity in your styles could be cascading over it.

Additionally: In the case of external linked style sheets, that concept will not work for many modern browsers using a linked style sheet with `@media print` styles inside if the style sheet has its `media` attribute value set to anything other than `print`.....UNLESS all the other non-print styles are inside a matching `@media screen{...}` rule in that sheet and you remove the "media=screen" attribute from the linked style sheet entirely (defaults to `media=all`). This may be what is happening in your internal print style example as the browser may assume your other styles are for both screen and print (all).

Many browsers currently will not support that type of mixed media query rule as they don't know what device your sheet and styles combined are designed for and mixing styles like this with without specific media attributes just confuses the parsers. If an external linked parent style sheet says it is set to "screen", it assumes all styles in there are for screen and vice versa. An so it would fail in allowing any print styles to be defined inside. Use of inline styles on elements is even worse as far as defining media type as they would apply to all media types by default.

Older browsers at one time supported a variety of combined media settings like this, but the consensus now is to use external linked sheets for print as it's cross-browser compatible going back to older browsers pre-2001.

**BEST PRACTICES FOR PRINT IN CSS**

The best way to do print style is to place them in linked sheets specifically set for screen and print as shown below...

```
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />
```

In that print sheet you don't need the `@media print` query any longer as everything in the style sheet with "media=print" will only be seen by printers. But if you do, it also should work ok. It would just be redundant.

There also is another option using the format `@import 'print.css' print;`. But I don't recommend that as a large number of browsers do not support the media type in @import, including Internet Explorer 1-7 and many others which would ignore this rule and not import the sheet.

You do NOT need `!important` in any of those rules, EXCEPT if you used `!important` in your regular style sheets. Those styles would override print sheet values, too. To cascade over those selectors, you would need a more selective copy of that selector or class in your print sheet with the `!important` value set to properties that match those in your screen sheet's style class.

This is yet another reason to not use `!important` in style sheets unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score -1):

"@media print" & < style media="print" > not working Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build). only style  media="print"